# Do I need to include the preposition "with" in the sentence below

Tags: prepositions

Our professional, personable staff is committed to providing you the best services and support.

Shouldn't it be:
Our professional, personable staff is committed to providing you with the best services and support.

Comment: Our professional, personable staff **are** committed, and yes, use with as a courtesy.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry In Britain we would say **are** (as we would say Arsenal **are** winning), but don't Americans use the singular with sports teams and organisations - as in *Microsoft is...*?

Comment: MicroSoft is **a** corporation, it's staff are numerous

Comment: @JonMarkPerry But most people in Britain would say *Microsoft are issuing an update to version xyz*

Answer (score 1):

"Provide" in the sense "to supply" can be both transitive and intransitive. So no, a preposition is not necessary here.

Note: "You" is not a direct object here, as can be easily demonstrated by replacing "providing" with "writing" and "services and support" with "letters of recommendation".

See also https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/provide

Comment: No. Though _provide_ can certainly be used in transitive and intransitive roles, (as mentioned in the 2-day old duplicate) a ditransitive usage is not licensed. Even your M-W reference uses 'with' rather than two non-prepositional objects.

Comment: I stand corrected. When using an indirect object (in the example, "you"), it seems you do indeed need to include the preposition "with".